# TFS build agents don't satisfy tge demands

Tags: tfs

I upgraded tfs to 2018.2 and i added a phase in my build to run ui tests. The build failed because "no agent found in the pool which satisfy the specified demands: oldMachines, vstest, agent.version -gtVersion 2.103.0". My agents have vstest and their version is 2.122.1, and when i try to use these agents in another release it succeeded to run the ui tests.

Comment: but my version is newer

Comment: does it have the `oldmachines` capability configured?